S3.addEventNotification to trigger lambda - getting AccessDenied because no permissions boundary allows the s3:GetBucketNotification
I'm using AWS CDK with TypeScript
I'm creating a lambda in a stack which should be triggered by a new folder being created in a S3 bucket that's created in another stack.
// S3 Bucket
const Bucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(this, "myBucket", `myBucketName`);

// Lambda
// For simplicity, creating newLambda function here 

Bucket.grantReadWrite(this.newLambda);

// Trigger from s3
this.newLambda.addEventSource(
  new lambdaEventSources.S3EventSourceV2(Bucket, {
    events: [s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
    filters: [{ prefix: "folder path" }],
  }),
);

In the lambda's role, I have give it ['s3:Get*', 's3:List*', 's3:Put*', 's3:Create*', 's3:Delete*'] to the s3 bucket
Now when I deploy this, I'm getting this error:
Error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: User: arn:aws:sts::281066629250:assumed-role/TempCreatedRole is not authorized to perform: s3:GetBucketNotification on resource: "Bucket" because no permissions boundary allows the s3:GetBucketNotification action.

What am I missing exactly? Should I add something to the bucket's policy? I even tried creating the trigger using s3notifiction like this but getting the same error:
Bucket.addEventNotification(
    s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED,
    new s3n.LambdaDestination(this.newLambda),
    {prefix: 'folder path'}
);

